# Can I use a global variable at the start of my code when I have defined it at the end of my program?

Tags: python, variables, global

The code I am using is shown here:

```
import os.path

def def1():
    global filename
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == True:
        print ("Filename exists")
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == False:
        print("Filename dosent exist")

def def2():
    global filename
    filename = input("Please input the name if the file you want to see exists")

def Main():
    def1()
    def2()

Main()
```

What the code does is check whether or not a file exists, and the user can input the name of the file he/she wishes to check. This code will be used in a much bigger code file. I am not able to understand why I get this error when I run the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/Sid/Desktop/existfiletest.py", line 18, in <module>
  Main()
 File "/Users/Sid/Desktop/existfiletest.py", line 15, in Main
  def1()
 File "/Users/Sid/Desktop/existfiletest.py", line 5, in def1
  if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == True:
NameError: name 'filename' is not defined
```

I have defined the variable 'filename' as a global in def2(), but I start off the program by calling def1(). The variable 'filename' is a global, so I don't see why it can't be used in def1(). And also, if anyone says to call def2() first, yes that works. However I would like to know whether I can use a variable before defining it, as this is the case in my bigger code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The same thing happens.

Comment: How can you use a variable before defining it? Python is not old Fortran. But then even in old Fortran the `type` is still defined. In Python, you cannot use a variable without defining it

Answer (score 1):

Sort answer:

replace:

```
    def Main():
       def1()
       def2()
```

by

```
    def Main():
       def2()
       def1()
```

Your mistake is not the fact that you defined the global variable earlier in the file. But by calling `def1` first, you have left the variable undefined. So you must call `def2` first to initialize and give it a value.

Secondly you do not need to perform the if test twice:

```
 def def1(filename):
     if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == True:
          print ("Filename exists")
     else:
          print("Filename does not exist")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use global variables. It is really bad practice. Use function arguments. You can change you code to:

```
import os.path

def def1(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == True:
        print ("Filename exists")
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == False:
        print("Filename dosent exist")

def def2():
    return input("Please input the name if the file you want to see exists")

def Main():
    filename = def2()
    def1(filename)

Main()
```

And of course you can't use variable before defining it. But you can define it with some default value.

Comment: Thanks! But is there any way of doing this using global variables? I have used global variables in my whole code - this is just a small extract of that code.

Comment: @Kronixion You never have to use global variables. But as I say you can define it with some default value in `def1`

Answer (score 0):

Save the filename in the main function and then pass it to the def1 function like so:

```
import os.path

def def1(filename):
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == True:
        print ("Filename exists")
    if os.path.isfile(filename+ ".txt") == False:
        print("Filename dosent exist")

def Main():
    filename = input("Please input the name if the file you want to see exists")
    def1(filename)

Main()
```